# php imagecreate function nothing displays

Tags: php

I am trying to create a server banner just like this

[image]

I tired to follow the tutorial here http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php

but the image does not show any info or the image don't show, I had it working when starting from the example  the data I am able to see in html echoed out just not the image..

```
 $servers = [
    [
        'id' => 'CS1',
        'banner' => 'b1.png',
        'type' => 'CS',
        'host' => '74.23.145.219:8777'  
    ]
];

$GameQ = new \GameQ\GameQ();
$GameQ->addServers($servers);
$GameQ->setOption('timeout', 5);
$GameQ->addFilter('normalize');
$results = $GameQ->process();


header("Content-type: image/png");
$results['id']['gq_address'];
$results['id']['gq_port_client'];
$results['id']['gq_name'];
$results['id']['ip'];
$results['id']['online'];
$results['id']['host_name'];


$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/banners/['banner']");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($results)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $results, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

> link

```
<img src="../includes/create_banner.php?gq_address=gq_port_client">
```

Comment: $im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/banners/['banner']");
That cant work. It you try to access an array, you miss the var-name $results['id']['banner']